# Polymer, observe global path, please

Tags: polymer, global, object.observe

In `Polymer 1.0` you can drop `{{localPropFoo.bar}}` and `bar` will be observed for changes if you use `this.set('localPropFoo.bar', 'new value');` to update its value.

But what to do if you want to bind template to an external object which is out of your control? E.g., this `{{window.globalFoo.bar}}` won't be bound to `bar` changes because external code doesn't depend on `Polymer` and doesn't call `this.set`.

[Demo on codepen](http://codepen.io/ilyaigpetrov/pen/YyydEW?editors=100)

Using `Object.observe` manually requires extra code and doesn't work in FireFox (dirty checks of [observe.js](https://github.com/polymer/observe-js) to the rescue).

I want to know what is the idiomatic way of data binding to external objects out of your control.

Comment: Have you tried iron-signals? It can listen to any iron-signal-* event regardless of its location in the DOM.

Comment: Idiomatic way is not to bind to external objects out of your control. Are you using other libraries that set it? If you control your whole app then there should be no need for it.

Comment: observe-js is your only helper here, but it is clumsy approach

Comment: @Andrey I use my own library which I don't want to depend on Polymer, but I can make it emit events in some way, maybe with Node's `EventEmitter`.

Comment: @ilyaigpetrov you can use native JS events

Comment: You can alway pass change by [custom event](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html),this is how polymer achieve observe.

Answer (score 0):

`Polymer` doesn't do observation out of the box, because:

1. `Object.observe` support is not ubiquitous and dirty checks are expensive.
2. `Object.observe` may be expensive on itself.

#### Supposed Solution

Catch changes yourself, call `notifyPath`, `this.fire('global-foo-changed', {path: 'globalFoo.bar', value:...}`, `this.set` and `this.push`.
They all dispatch corresponding non-bubbling (capturing) `globalFoo-changed` custom events (only when needed).

#### Why my `global-foo-changed` events affect only `this` element?

1. `global-foo-changed` events are capturing (non-bubbling).
2. Polymer elements listen for bubbling events by default.
3. For some reason these capturing listeners capture bubble events dispatched from the same element (not from its children). [Demo on codepen](http://codepen.io/ilyaigpetrov/pen/VvaWjx?editors=100).

You may patch polymer with this behavior (**I don't understand how it works**):

```
SharedGlobalsBehavior = {
  properties: {
    globalFoo: {
      type: Object,
      notify: true,
      value: globalFoo
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    window.addEventListener('global-foo-changed', () => {
      if (!event.detail || !event.detail.path)
        return; // Property initialization.
      this.notifyPath(event.detail.path, event.detail.value);
    },/* if capturing */ true);
  }
};
```

### Why No Observation Out of the Box

> ...sometimes imperative code needs to change an object’s sub- properties directly. As we avoid more sophisticated observation mechanisms such as Object.observe or dirty-checking in order to achieve the best startup and runtime performance cross-platform for the most common use cases, changing an object’s sub-properties directly requires cooperation from the user.
>
> Specifically, Polymer provides two methods that allow such changes to be notified to the system: notifyPath(path, value) and set(path, value), where path is a string identifying the path (relative to the host element).